# How to use XCGLogger in a framework

Tags: swift, xcglogger

I want to use XCGLogger inside of a Swift framework I'm writing. The app that includes this framework may or may not use XCGLogger as well.

What's the best way to approach this sort of scenario? Would I use something like dependency injection to let the app send the XCGLogger instance to the framework? Where in the framework would I call XCGLogger's setup method?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Not really.. I'm just using a separate logger instance from the framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to use the same logger in the project and a framework by simply referencing the same `XCGLogger.defaultInstance()` in both.

First, `import XCGLogger` in the imports, Then instantiate the log instance in the project using `let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()`.

After that I instantiate the `sharedInstance` of the framework I'm using (per my particular use case).

Within the framework, `import XCGLogger` & instantiate the logger `let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()` before my `Class` declarations.

Then, back in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate.swift`, I do the `log.setup(...your params...)`.

In the case of you authoring the framework, you'll want some logic and readme notes to setup the logger if one isn't setup the way you prefer.

Probably not the most elegant way to get it done, but it does work.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install 'XCGLogger' with `pods`

```
use_frameworks!

target '<YouAppName>' do
pod 'XCGLogger'
```

`import XCGLogger` in `AppDelegate.swift'

In `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` configure XCGLogger with

```
    //Setting up XCGLogger shared instance ()
    XCGLogger.defaultInstance().setup(.Debug, showLogLevel: true, showFileNames: true, showLineNumbers: true, writeToFile: nil, fileLogLevel: .Debug)
```

Suppose I want to use `XCGLogger` in my `BLUserServicesCD.swift`. So, `import XCGLogger` at the top of the file.
Create a variable `private let Logger = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()` and log using

`Logger.info("USER DELETED SUCCESSFULLY")` OR

`Logger.error("COULD NOT DELETE USER \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")`

Also try to use these followings useful methods as required.

[image]

For more details please refer to [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger)

Comment: The OP was asking how to integrate XCGLogger into a framework they are building. While your answer is thorough on how to integrate XCGLogger easily into an app/project, it doesn't solve the OP's question.